# Layout issue for imageview Android

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem in adding an image at the end of the  linear layout in android. 
It is always added at the begining.
My   question:

1. How to add this image at the end of the Layout?
2. Afterwards can I add ab element from beginning?

Comment: Can you show us the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Layout [Tricks](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/)